# Accessing resource from osgi bundle: bundle scheme in the URL lead to a malformed exception

Tags: java, url, resources, osgi, protocols

#### Question

Is there a means to build a java.net.URL object from its constructor with "bundle" as scheme in an osgi context ?

#### Exemple

```
URL url = new URL("bundle://<bundle-id>/path/file.txt");
InputStream in = url.openStream();
...
```

This code lead to a malformed exception (unknown protocol) when the stream is open. I don't know how the osgi platform register new schemes to the java.net.URL

#### Context and ideal solution

I want to configure a service thanks to Configuration Admin. This configuration contains a property to set a file path. I would like the consumer to be able to store the file where he want (file system, inside bundle or even internet).

The previous exemple could be great because the code is simple and the consumer could provide path of the form: "bundle:///path/file.txt", "file:///path/file.txt", "http:///path/file.tx", but infortunatly it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Only the framework can construct those URLs. You can use a Bundle object to return URLs for content in a bundle.

Comment: OK, so no choice there is an external  dependency. Do you know which method I can use to open generic URL?

Comment: To be more specific, is there a standard method from the OSGI Framework which accept a string like "bundle:///path/file.txt" or "file:///path/file.txt" and return a valid java.net.URL object ?

Comment: You cannot go new URL("bundle:..."). The bundle protocol handler is not installed in the JVM. It is private to the framework. If you know the path of a resource in a bundle, then you can call Bundle.getResource("/path/file.txt") or Bundle.getEntry("/path/file.txt") depending upon if you want to use the bundle's class loader to find the resource or just look in the bundle.